# Matlab figure multiple cursor bars

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I found a code from File Exchange that's almost exactly what I wanted.  It's supposed to let me plot vertical cursors and move around with the mouse.  Except, it doesn't move.  The code was revised last back in 2011 and I'm using 2018b version.  I tried to debug a bit, but I couldn't figure out why WindowButtonMotionFcn doesn't invoke a subroutine CursorButtonDownFcn.  The function is just not called when I grab a cursor and try to move it around.  Did some of the functions being called in the code have become obsolete?  If so, what are replacements for them?

The code is found: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14093-data-cursors-for-figure-window

Comment: What are you asking? I could paraphrase this question as "I found a function which doesn't quite do what I want, here it is". Questions are off topic if they are too broad, unclear, and/or asking for off-site recommendations. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] for what you're trying to achieve, including formatted code, and perhaps a simple mock-up of what you'd like the cursor to actually do. If you're just asking someone to update the FileExchange submission to work for your MATLAB version, that's a comment for the FE submission itself.

Comment: @Wolfie Sorry that I was clear.  Can you or somebody help me understand why at the current state of this code the CursorButtonDownFcn is not invoked even though WindowButtonMotionFcn is activated (?) when I try to move around a cursorbar?  It's a debugging question and in a sense, you are right that I'm saying what you said I was saying.  With my insufficient knowledge on WindowButtonMotionFcn, I couldn't figure that out myself.  Even with breakpoints, since I can't debug WindowButtonMotionFcn, I can't debug why CursorButtonDownFcn isn't invoked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], this makes it so we can reproduce your issue